# Two InputConnection variable in InputMethodService?

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am trying to implement own android IME. In `InputMethodService.onStartInputView` I save a reference to `InputConnection` returned by `getCurrentInputConnection` for later use. And on keyup event I call `InputConnection.commitText` to commit some text onto screen.

But I find that in some apps, that function call has no effect (That is nothing appear on screen) whereas
the softKeyBoard sdk sample works well. The only difference is that the sample is using `getCurrentInputConnect` to commit chars. Additionally , the statement in my app is **false**

```
mCurrentInputConnection == Ime.getCurrentInputConnection()
```

In [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/ics-mr0-release/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.java) of IME service there're two InputConnection members: mInputConnection and mStartedInputConnection and `getCurrentInputConnection` may return either.

I know I could call `getCurrentInputConnection` each time but I simply want to avoid a function call for performance issue(because that will be called too often). So is there any other approach to get the **correct** InputConnection? (and what's the difference between the two?)

Answer (score 0):

Your single instance of `InputConnection` stops working because once you open some other application or change the editText field, a new client has bound with your IME and hence the input connection has changed.

If you want to avoid multiple calls to `getCurrentInputConnection()` over and over then you can store a `InputConnection` object every time it changes. The callback for it is [onBindInput](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onBindInput()).